# How to solve - ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found

Tags: java, gradle, logging, intellij-idea

Using Intellij I am getting the error below when running in the IDE -

> ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user
>   programmatically provided configurations. Set system property
>   'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See
>   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for
>   instructions on how to configure Log4j 2

When I run the jar file -

> trevor@trevor-Lenovo-YOGA-510-14AST:~/decent/Master5/out/artifacts/Master5_main_jar$
>   java -jar Master5.main.jar  Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory   at
>   BlockgetConnection.(BlockgetConnection.java:12)   at
>   BlockgetAccount.getAccountByName(BlockgetAccount.java:31)     at
>   BlockgetStart.main(BlockgetStart.java:8) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 3 more

I am not explicitly logging and I assume in the Decent logic there is a need to log somehow. I included my build.gradle. I have included some dependencies for logging. Any idea about the solution?

Code (main class) -

```
import ch.decent.sdk.model.Account;

public class BlockgetStart {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockgetAccount anAccount = new BlockgetAccount();
        Account myAcct = anAccount.getAccountByName("trevor3");
    }

}
```

Instance of this class used -

```
import ch.decent.sdk.DCoreApi;
import ch.decent.sdk.crypto.Address;
import ch.decent.sdk.crypto.Credentials;
import ch.decent.sdk.model.Account;
import ch.decent.sdk.model.AssetAmount;
import ch.decent.sdk.model.Fee;
import ch.decent.sdk.model.TransactionConfirmation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

@Component
public class BlockgetAccount {
    // connection to accounts
    private static final Long AMOUNT_OF_DCT_REQUIRED_FOR_CREATION = 100000L;

    @Autowired
    private BlockgetConnection connectionExample;
    @Autowired
    private BlockgetLogin loginExample;
    @Autowired
    private BlockgetGenerateKeys generateKeys;

    /**
     * Example of getting any account by its name.
     *
     * @param accountName name of the account e.g. dw-account
     * @return Account instance for given account name
     */
    public Account getAccountByName(String accountName) {

        connectionExample = new BlockgetConnection();
        final DCoreApi dcoreApi = connectionExample.connect();

        return dcoreApi
                .getAccountApi()
                .getByName(accountName)
                .blockingGet();
    }

    /**
     * Example of account creation with initial fee.
     *
     * @param newAccountName Unique account name that you wish to create.
     * @return Confirmation about transaction
     */
    public TransactionConfirmation createAccount(String newAccountName) {

        final DCoreApi dcoreApi = connectionExample.connect();
        final Credentials credentials = loginExample.login();
        final Address newAccountPublicKey = generateKeys.generateKeys();
        final AssetAmount dctAssetAmount = new AssetAmount(AMOUNT_OF_DCT_REQUIRED_FOR_CREATION);
        final Fee initialFee = new Fee(dctAssetAmount.getAssetId(), AMOUNT_OF_DCT_REQUIRED_FOR_CREATION);

        return dcoreApi.getAccountApi().create(
                credentials,
                newAccountName,
                newAccountPublicKey,
                initialFee
        ).blockingGet();
    }
}
```

Build.gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.blockget.Master5'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar { manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'BlockgetStart' } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-ap
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.26'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.12.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.DECENTfoundation:DCoreKt-SDK:2.3.1'

}
```

I get this for the jar breakdown -

```
    trevor@trevor-Lenovo-YOGA-510 
    14AST:~/decent/Master5/out/artifacts/Master5_main_jar$ jar tf 
    Master5.main.jar 
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    META-INF/
    BlockgetNftMgr.class
    BlockgetLogin.class
    BlockgetConnection.class
    BlockgetNft.class
    BlockgetStart.class
    BlockgetAccount.class
    BlockgetGenerateKeys.class
```

Should Logger be in here?

Comment: I added the following and removed the Apache logging which removed the IDE error. The CLI one still remains -     compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.26'

Comment: If you are getting only NoClassDefFoundError, try to add the implementation slf4j dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12

Comment: I have that already in the build.gradle file.

Comment: When I try classpath on the CLI it is empty. I am unsure if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was as follows

- Open Project Settings

  - Select Artifacts
  - Click + to add a new artifact, select JAR and then the class
  - For Jar Files, select "Copy to the output directory and link via manifest"
  - (this is not the default)
  - Click OK and then Apply

For the Manifest I did not take the default either but used the root level for the project.

After all this, the jars all were together and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you mark "resource" directory as a "Resources Root"?

In that case you will need to put the **log4j2.xml** file under src folder in order to be able to find it on the classpath. Put it under **src/main/resources** or **src/test/resources**.

Other solution: use system property **-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/path/to/file/log4j2.xml**

Comment: log4j2.json is under src/main/resources and resources is marked as a resources root, but nothing has changed. Still got the exception. Any tips?